# Central backup for google apps standard

Tags: email-server, g-suite

Do you know how to do a full backup of ALL users emails when using Google Apps Standard?

What about docs, calendars etc.?

Is it by any chance possibiity to automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you need to be able to use the Google Apps API (then you can write a script or something), which you don't get access to under Stardard.

So, not unless you open your chequebook.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable imap and sync it either with another imap server or with maildir files.

Some tools: [offlineimap](http://software.complete.org/offlineimap) mailsync imapsync isync . I've used offlineimap for imap<->maildir<->imap syncs.

Comment: That wouldn't allow you to back up all users' e-mails unless you had all of their passwords.